# How to change data label displaying value of different column in Power BI Desktop

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

Stacked column chart displays `Running Total budget` vs `Running Total Premium` for each month. I also created New measurement:

```
Percentage = 
DIVIDE( [RunningPremium], SUM(SafetyBudget[RunningTotalForecast]))
```

Which gives me this result:
[image]

But how to display value of the `Percentage` column in `Running Total Premium` data label? Instead of 1.3M should be 166%, instead 2.7M should be 149% etc.

So basically I want to keep chart as is, but display different value  in data label. 
Something like this:

[image]

I tried to add Percentage column as another `'value'`, but still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not yet achievable in Power BI.

When you add the `Percentage` column to the `Value` section, no result is shown because the values are so small (0~1) and negligible compared with the other values like the running sums (which is in millions).

The closest you can get in Power BI is to add the `Percentage` column to the Tooltips. That way, when you hover over the stacked bar, the tooltip value will be displayed.

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is too old but you can try Line and stacked bar, add the percentage to Line and put stroke to zero and data labels to On.

Answer (score 0):

If your model has a **column having Percentage format** Power BI chart will automatically show it with percentage sign by multiplying it with 100.